# Maintenance mode - authorize with something other than IP

Tags: php, laravel

I want to load website for my self . I know I should edit storage/framework/down to let my IP pass. But for a reason I'm always using a VPN so My IP is dynamic.
I want to authorize my self with something else like cookie,user agent etc...
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write custom middleware to check if request is allowed to pass through maintenance mode:

1. run `php artisan make:middleware AllowMaintenanceModeMiddleware`
2. Then put `AllowMaintenanceModeMiddleware` in `app/Http/Kernel.php` `$middleware` property
3. Check custom condition in `AllowMaintenanceModeMiddleware` 's handle method

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    /* Here you can put your own condigions to pass through maintenance mode */
    if($this->app->isDownForMaintenance() && $request->allowme == null) {
        throw new MaintenanceModeException(strtotime('now + 1 hour'));
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

4. don't forget to import: `use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Exceptions\MaintenanceModeException;`

> Don't  forget to put custom `MaintenanceModeException` middleware before      `\App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class` in `Kernel.php` file, otherwise default middleware will cancel request and throws `MaintenanceModeException` before accessing custom.

Hope this helps you